# CentOS 7 bridge only single NIC active at a time

Tags: linux, centos, networking, network-interface, bridge

Hoping I am missing something obvious.
All setup done using nmtui so config files should not have any manual errors.

I have bridge br0 with slaves eth2 and eth3

br0 has IP 192.168.77.1

eth2 has client on IP 192.168.77.10

eth3 has client on IP 192.168.77.15

With the above setup I can only ping br0 via eth2.

As soon as I remove eth2 I can ping via eth3.

If I add eth2 back i can only ping via eth2 again.

What's the catch?

I want br0 to act equivalently to hardware switch where it will pass traffic to any slave as required.

EDIT:

Noticed eth3 MAC is duplicated in the bridge's forwarding table.

Answer (score 0):

Are you running in under  Wmware workstation ? 
make sure you have unchecked TAP- Windows Ada [image]